# Правила сортировки для нулевых значений

Tags: php, сортировка, pdo

Данный код PHP сортирует элементы по цене (убыванию/возрастанию), но в списке есть элементы с нулевой ценой ("Цена по запросу") и нужно чтобы они выводились в конце.

Вопрос: как это можно реализовать?

```html
$sort = $this->_getParam('sort');
$sort = $sort === 'ordr' ? '' : $sort;
$sort_type = $this->_getParam('sort_type');

if ($sort) {
    if ($sort_type == 'desc') {
        $products->setOrderField('price DESC');
    } else {
        $products->setOrderField('price ASC');
    }
}
```

Есть ещё старый код:

```
$products->setOrderField(($sort == 'price' || $sort == 'price_param' ? 'isprice desc, price_param' : $sort) . ' ' . $sort_type);
```

Но, но выдаёт ошибку:

```html
An error occurred
Exception information:
Message: Select query cannot join with another table

Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/u0221427/data/www/irice.ru/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(468): Zend_Db_Table_Select->assemble()
#1 /var/www/u0221427/data/www/irice.ru/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query(Object(Zend_Db_Table_Select), Array)
#2 /var/www/u0221427/data/www/irice.ru/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php(1577): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query(Object(Zend_Db_Table_Select))
#3 /var/www/u0221427/data/www/irice.ru/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php(1392): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->_fetch(Object(Zend_Db_Table_Select))
#4 /var/www/u0221427/data/www/irice.ru/application/models/mappers/EntityMapper.php(140): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->fetchAll(Object(Zend_Db_Table_Select))
#5 /var/www/u0221427/data/www/irice.ru/application/models/mappers/EntityMapper.php(61): A_Model_Mapper_EntityMapper->doFindAllBy(Array, Array)
#6 /var/www/u0221427/data/www/irice.ru/application/models/collections/AbstractCollection.php(65): A_Model_Mapper_EntityMapper->__call('doFindAllBy', Array)
#7 /var/www/u0221427/data/www/irice.ru/application/models/collections/AbstractCollection.php(83): A_Model_Collection_AbstractCollection->notifyAccess()
#8 /var/www/u0221427/data/www/irice.ru/application/models/collections/AbstractCollection.php(94): A_Model_Collection_AbstractCollection->getRow(0)
#9 /var/www/u0221427/data/www/irice.ru/application/models/collections/AbstractCollection.php(117): A_Model_Collection_AbstractCollection->current()
#10 /var/www/u0221427/data/www/irice.ru/application/views/scripts/catalog/list.phtml(2): A_Model_Collection_AbstractCollection->valid()
#11 /var/www/u0221427/data/www/irice.ru/application/views/scripts/catalog/view.phtml(212): include('/var/www/u02214...')
#12 /var/www/u0221427/data/www/irice.ru/library/Zend/View.php(157): include('/var/www/u02214...')
#13 /var/www/u0221427/data/www/irice.ru/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(888): Zend_View->_run('/var/www/u02214...')
#14 /var/www/u0221427/data/www/irice.ru/library/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php(912): Zend_View_Abstract->render(NULL)
#15 /var/www/u0221427/data/www/irice.ru/library/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php(933): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->renderScript('catalog/view.ph...', NULL)
#16 /var/www/u0221427/data/www/irice.ru/library/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php(972): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->render()
#17 /var/www/u0221427/data/www/irice.ru/library/Zend/Controller/Action/HelperBroker.php(277): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->postDispatch()
#18 /var/www/u0221427/data/www/irice.ru/library/Zend/Controller/Action.php(527): Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker->notifyPostDispatch()
#19 /var/www/u0221427/data/www/irice.ru/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(308): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('viewAction')
#20 /var/www/u0221427/data/www/irice.ru/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#21 /var/www/u0221427/data/www/irice.ru/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(105): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#22 /var/www/u0221427/data/www/irice.ru/library/Zend/Application.php(384): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#23 /var/www/u0221427/data/www/irice.ru/index.php(55): Zend_Application->run()
#24 {main}  
Request Parameters:


Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getParams() on array in /var/www/u0221427/data/www/irice.ru/application/views/scripts/error/error.phtml:23
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/u0221427/data/www/irice.ru/library/Zend/View.php(157): include()
#1 /var/www/u0221427/data/www/irice.ru/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(888): Zend_View->_run('/var/www/u02214...')
#2 /var/www/u0221427/data/www/irice.ru/library/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php(912): Zend_View_Abstract->render(NULL)
#3 /var/www/u0221427/data/www/irice.ru/library/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php(933): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->renderScript('error/error.pht...', NULL)
#4 /var/www/u0221427/data/www/irice.ru/library/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php(972): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->render()
#5 /var/www/u0221427/data/www/irice.ru/library/Zend/Controller/Action/HelperBroker.php(277): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->postDispatch()
#6 /var/www/u0221427/data/www/irice.ru/library/Z in /var/www/u0221427/data/www/irice.ru/application/views/scripts/error/error.phtml on line 23
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_cast.asp   После `CAST` значение `NULL` станет `INT` == 0

Comment: Придется сделать SELECT * FROM Table WHERE price > 0 UNION SELECT FROM Table WHERE price = 0;

Comment: @DanielProtopopov данный запрос ни коим образом не обеспечивает сортировку записей

Comment: @teran запрос обеспечивает получение списка с ненулевой ценой, которую автор может отсортировать как ему нужно, и в конце добавит записи с нулевой ценой. Про NULL он нигде и ни разу не упоминал.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov нет тут никакого "в конце" любые результаты выборки из бд не упорядочены пока там строго не будет указано `order by`

Comment: @teran век живи - век учись! был неправ, признаю :)

Answer (score 0):

ваша сортировка становится двухуровневой. на первом уровне сортируете нулл/не нулл, на втором цену.

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN price IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC
   , price DESC
```

то есть ваш код примет примерно такой вид

```
if ($sort) {
    $priceOrder = $sort_type == 'desc' ? 'DESC' : "ASC"; 
    $order = "CASE WHEN price IS NULL then 0 ELSE 1 END DESC
             , price $priceOrder";        // или прямо 'price $sortType'

    $products->setOrderField($order);

}
```

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, показать на моём примере как это будет выглядеть?

Comment: @maf понятия не имею, что за пхп обертку вы юзаете. попробуйте указать приведенный фрагмент (без order by) как параметрв `setOrderField`

Comment: Попробовал, выдало ошибку:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'CASE' (T_CASE) in /var/www/u0221427/data/www/irice.ru/application/controllers/CatalogController.php on line 308

Comment: Передал ввиде строки, но сртировка не сработала.

Comment: @maf ну не просто же так вставить то надо было, а строку передать `$products->setOrderField("CASE ... ")`

Comment: @maf price то у вас там 0 или NULL ? 0-1 кстати не на тех позициях у меня написаны, поправлю на  DESC

Comment: Вот пример страницы https://irice.ru/catalog/spalni/krovati/.
Именно 0, не NULL.
Попробовал Ваш пример:
Message: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't.CASE WHEN price IS NULL then 0 ELSE 1 END' in 'order clause', query was: SELECT `t`.* FROM `products` AS `t` WHERE (`t`.`Onoff` = 1) AND (`t`.`Category_Id` IN ('13')) ORDER BY `t`.`CASE WHEN price IS NULL then 0 ELSE 1 END` DESC, `t`.`price` ASC LIMIT 36

Comment: @maf изучайте фреймворк, который используете (что то от zend),   или по крайней мере абстракцию для работы с БД. Он подсталвяет алиас таблицы перед case, отсюда ошибка. зы: ну и по итогу надо не is null проверять а = 0